# Remove currency symbol from price in magento

Tags: magento, bundle, currency

How to remove currency symbol from price on the bundled products page only. There is one bundled product i want to remove currency symbol from the final price on that page

Answer (score 1):

```
$product = $this->getProduct();
if($product->getTypeId() === 'bundle'){     

Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->format(
    $product->getFinalPrice(), 
    array('display'=>Zend_Currency::NO_SYMBOL), 
    false
);    

}
```

You may have that work around in the  following file

```
app/design/frontend/default/YOUR_THEME/template/bundle/product/price.phtml
```

Comment: Edited my answer. There are lots of conditions there in the file you need to check.

Comment: the price code is not coming from that file for bundle product its coming from

Comment: app/design/frontend/default/YOUR_THEME/template/bundle/product/view/price.phtml

Answer (score 0):

Well, the xml file to edit depends upon your locale settings. My locale is set to English (United States). So, I will have to change en.xml file.

You can change your locale setting from
Admin Panel –> System –> Configuration –> GENERAL –> General –> Locale options –> Locale

If your locale is Japanese (Japan), you need to change lib/Zend/Locale/Data/ja.xml

If your locale is Hindi (India), you need to change lib/Zend/Locale/Data/ne.xml

It’s similar for other locale settings. I have locale setting as English, so I will be editing en.xml file.

- Open lib/Zend/Locale/Data/en.xml
- Find the following :-

> ```
> <currency type="NPR">
>     <displayName>Nepalese Rupee</displayName>
>     <displayName count="one">Nepalese rupee</displayName>
>     <displayName count="other">Nepalese rupees</displayName>
>     <symbol>Nrs</symbol>
> </currency>
> ```

- Change
  Nrs
  to
  Rs 
  **Or** Remove Symbol sign
- That’s it.

But wait, you are still not done. The most important thing is still left.

- Clear the Cache.
- Go to System –> Cache Management
- Refreh Cache.
- If you have not enabled the Cache OR if it didn’t work even after refreshing the cache, then
- delete the cache folder present inside var (var/cache)

Now, it should definitely work. :)

I changed the currency symbol for Nepalese Rupee. You can do similarly for your currency type.

Comment: I think he is asking for bundled products only. Can these changes be done only for bundled products?

Comment: this will effect to whole store i want only for bundled product. or is their any solution as like the currency on that page not change even when the customer change the currency from US to AED?

Answer (score 0):

**Please Try This below one line code It's working for me.**

```
<?php echo Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->format($_product->getFinalPrice(), array('display'=>Zend_Currency::NO_SYMBOL), false); ?>
```